# Macro to change an Outlook appointment to a meeting request

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a macro to change an Outlook appointment to a meeting request because many of my users are complaining that when they double-click a time in Outlook calendar, it used to open a meeting request but now by default opens an appointment.

Ive seen some macros like this:

```
Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
  If TypeName(m_Inspector.CurrentItem) = "AppointmentItem" And _
    m_Inspector.CurrentItem.CreationTime > Now Then
      m_Inspector.CurrentItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
  End If
End Sub
```

But I have no experience customizing this type of macro, can you help?

Comment: How would the condition `m_Inspector.CurrentItem.CreationTime > Now` ever be true?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [AppointmentItem.CreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.creationtime) property which returns a date indicating the creation time for the Outlook item doesn't make any sense because the date will never be equal to the date returned by the `Now` function. Instead, if you need to make sure that you are dealing with a newly created appointment item in Outlook you may check the `EntryID` property whether it is set or not:

```
Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
  If TypeName(m_Inspector.CurrentItem) = "AppointmentItem" And _
    m_Inspector.CurrentItem.EntryID = "" Then
      m_Inspector.CurrentItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
  End If
End Sub
```

Also you may use the [IsEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function) function available in VBA.